# How to skip non-valid (space separated) rows in csv file rather than skipping first N rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a `csv` file which looks like:

```
Provided by someone, unformatted by another-one for some purposes,
another-one would never hand out such a mess ;)

Have fun!

$ Column names
:azimuth:zenith:bjorkeny:energy:pos_x:pos_y:pos_z:proba_track:proba_cscd

$ Data
0:2,3495370211373316:1,1160038417256017:0,04899799823760986:3,3664000034332275:52,74:28,831:401,18600000000004:0,8243512974051896:0,17564870259481039
1:5,575785663044353:1,7428377336692398:0,28047099709510803:3,890000104904175:48,369:29,865:417,282:0,8183632734530938:0,18163672654690619
2:4,656124692722159:2,686909147834136:0,1198429986834526:3,2335000038146973:71,722:121,449:363,077:0,8283433133732535:0,17165668662674652
```

Reading that file in `pandas` requires skipping first rows, and defining comment as `$`:

```py
pd.read_csv(
  'data/neutrinos.csv', 
  on_bad_lines='skip', 
  sep=':',
  skiprows=5,
  comment='$',
  index_col=0,
  decimal=','
)
```

Is there a **more generic** approach where I can **skip all space-separated rows** without defining the number of rows to skip or the comment sign? thanks in advance.

Comment: `skiprows` accepts a callable, would `skiprows = lambda x: x >= 9 or x == 6` be sufficient?

Comment: @BeRT2me my question is about how to automate the process rather than assigning pre-defined numbers `5, 9, 6, etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your safest bet is to parse the csv file first, skipping any rows which only have 1 value and then using that as your input:

```
import csv
import io

csv.register_dialect('mycsv', delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

newcsv = ''
with open('test.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, 'mycsv')
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 1:
            newcsv += ':'.join(row) + '\n'

df = pd.read_csv(
  io.StringIO(newcsv), 
  sep=':',
  index_col=0,
  decimal=','
)
```

Output:

```
    azimuth    zenith  bjorkeny  energy   pos_x    pos_y    pos_z  proba_track  proba_cscd
0  2.349537  1.116004  0.048998  3.3664  52.740   28.831  401.186     0.824351    0.175649
1  5.575786  1.742838  0.280471  3.8900  48.369   29.865  417.282     0.818363    0.181637
2  4.656125  2.686909  0.119843  3.2335  71.722  121.449  363.077     0.828343    0.171657
```

Note that for a large file, you will probably want to build the dataframe row by row (in the csv reader loop) rather than creating a huge `newcsv` string.

**Don't try this at work**

For your sample data, in a **non-production environment**, you could use a side-effect from an `on_bad_lines` callback to populate a list with the *actual* rows:

```py
data = []
_ = pd.read_csv('test.csv', on_bad_lines=lambda l:data.append(l), sep=':', index_col=0, decimal=',', engine='python')
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=['idx'] + data[0][1:]).set_index('idx')
```

Output:

```
                azimuth              zenith  ...         proba_track           proba_cscd
idx                                          ...
0    2.3495370211373316  1.1160038417256017  ...  0.8243512974051896  0.17564870259481039
1     5.575785663044353  1.7428377336692398  ...  0.8183632734530938  0.18163672654690619
2     4.656124692722159   2.686909147834136  ...  0.8283433133732535  0.17165668662674652
```

Answer (score 1):

CASE-I : Assuming the first '$' is the column headers.
I cannot find any 'pandas' solution for this, but there is one other way that this can be achieved:-

```
with open('C:/Users/r.goyal/Desktop/sample.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

skiprows = [i for i in range(len(lines)) if lines[i][0]=='$'][0]
```

This will give you value of skiprows for the parameter 'skiprows' in pandas.read_csv().

For large CSVs where million of rows are present and execution time is a sensitive factor, the same can be improvised to -

```
skiprows = 0; i=0
with open('C:/Users/r.goyal/Desktop/sample.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0]=='$':
            skiprows = i
            break
        i+=1
```

CASE-II (Assuming nothin)

```
skiprows = 0; i=0
with open('C:/Users/r.goyal/Desktop/sample.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.split(':')) > len(line.split(" ")):
            skiprows = i-1 # -1 to reach the line that mentions $ Columns
            break

        i+=1
```

The space-separated rows will have more spaces than the ':' separated rows, and hence the comparison is done on the same logic.